# Are there other encoding methods besides base64 that end in "="?

Tags: encryption, asp-classic, base64, tripledes

I've inherited a project where the previous developer is using an ASP object called `ActiveCrypt.Crypt` to encrypt the users password before sending it to the database.

The call uses the `encryptvariant()` function with a mode of 7, which the only documentation I can find indicates that the encrpytion is 3DES (company is now defunct). The problem is, that the value derived from the function appears to be a base64-encoded string (the trailing single and double "==" are a dead give-away).

Are there any other encodings that frequently end in "=" or "=="? Is anyone familiar with this ActiveCrypt object? I've tried 3DES encoding the password, with the key, then converting to base64, but with no luck. I've also tried inverting the key and the password in case the developer swapped the arguments. Any help would be appreciated.

Some examples using the key "key" (without quotes)

```
abcdefg: xiupz3RT148=

123456: iDLXPSPPjd4=

test: AWulSF10FR0=

1234567890: 8I48MAg9YWvE3y52VfMYew==
```

Comment: Sure looks like Base64. Do you have reason to believe it's not? Seems more likely that you're seeing the Base64-encoded output of an unknown (or partially-known) encryption scheme.

Comment: Have you checked it with [all variants of Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history)?

Answer (score 0):

The encodings you show look like 8 and 16 bytes encoded with normal base64. Base64 encodes 3 bytes using 4 characters. DES and 3DES operate with block size of 8 bytes. So the sizes of the base64 text seem to reflect the block size. Furthermore, the output of the base 64 decoding looks fully random.

So after base64 decoding you will have 8 or 16 bytes, which you then will have to decrypt. The key is of course unknown to us, as is the block mode of operation and the padding mode. So you will have to find out those yourself. If the key is not given, it could be hard coded within the application.

Happy hunting.